# Trying to set up Amazon S3 filesystem in Apache Commons VFS in java

Tags: java, amazon-s3, apache-commons-vfs

I'm trying to use [VFS S3](http://code.google.com/p/vfs-s3/) a plugin for the [Apache Commons VFS](http://commons.apache.org/vfs/) for [Amazon S3](http://aws.amazon.com/s3/).

I've included the jar and it's recognising the `s3` schema.

However when I try to open a file (which is public, I can open it on my web browser), I get this error:

```
Could not create a file system manager of class "org.apache.commons.vfs.impl.StandardFileSystemManager".
>> org.apache.commons.vfs.VFS.createManager(VFS.java:93)
>> org.apache.commons.vfs.VFS.getManager(VFS.java:47)
```

What should I do?

Comment: Is it the full stack trace? is there a "caused by" section?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've fixed this myself another way. Turns out that library depends on some other java libraries (like log4j from apache and jets3t from amazon). It just wasn't giving a helpful error message at all.

Answer (score 1):

You should debug it and fix it yourself, or contact the vendor of the library.

By "vendor", I mean the person/entity/organization who distributes the software, not **necessarily** "who is selling the library", heh.

Comment: You can: check the mailing list, web forum, email the developer(s), read version control logs, Change log file, search the bug tracker.

Answer (score 1):

Please check out the new [VFSLib Java library](http://www.leisenfels.com/products/vfslib). It comes with support for Amazon S3, Google Drive, and Dropbox altogether. Get premium support for first-hand information directly from vendor.