# Is there a mime type aware virtual file system with OS and S3 bindings in Java?

Tags: java, amazon-s3, apache-commons-vfs

I'm looking for an abstraction that provides access to the operating system's file system and S3 in the same way. However, it want to be able to set and get the file's mime type explicitly.

In case of the operating system's file system it would just be ignored, in case of S3 it would actually be passed to [set the files mime type explicitly](http://www.jets3t.org/api/org/jets3t/service/model/StorageObject.html#setContentType%28java.lang.String%29).

I did notice the [Amazon S3 driver for Apache commons-vfs](https://github.com/abashev/vfs-s3), but that one doesn't allow me to set the mime type explicitly. In fact, I couldn't even find a way how you could do that in [commons-vfs](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-vfs/) in general. If anybody knows, I'd love to know.

Comment: [duplicate](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1342655/trying-to-set-up-amazon-s3-filesystem-in-apache-commons-vfs-in-java?rq=1)?

Comment: No, not a duplicate. This is not about using commons-vfs. It's about passing mime type, to make sure it's set explicitly on S3.